# How to access local file directory to select a file using flutter?

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to access the local mobile directory and access files using flutter? if so how?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can access (store/retrieve) data in mobile storage via [shared_preference](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)
further you can serialize your data with [JSON Serialization](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json)

I'm guessing it's what you meant to ask.

Comment: well i need to get the file from local directory and upload it to cloud firestore. how does this differ from [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker)